# How to disable the touch delay at bottom of the screen when control center access is enabled in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I'm working on an app which has buttons at the bottom of the screen(looks like tab bar). I found that if I enable the access to control center in app, there will be a notable delay between tapping on the buttons and the highlighted image showing. In fact the highlighted image will never show if I do not hold on the touch for at least about 0.5 second. I'm wondering if there is a way to disable the delay even the access of control center in app is ON so that users of my app will know the buttons did have been tapped. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the delay. Because for a user experience, when user tries to access the control center and looking at the highlighting tab bar item looks uncomfortable. So i think it's better to leave it as it is.

Comment: @Dinesh Raja, thanks for the comment. Maybe you are right, when the user want to access to control center, they may not be willing to see the buttons' status changing. But I still want to know, is there a way I can disable the delay in case that my boss want me to do that. You know, when it is not my own app, I don't have the authority to determine the behavior of it.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23046539/1953914 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20780024/1953914